# How do I read different inputs from scanner in Java?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I need to get various integral inputs and then when `-1` is entered, the program should show the largest, smallest, sum of all entered, number of values of all entered, and the mean of all values entered. I have started a loop to take various inputs but cannot find a suitable way to read them and then play with them. I have searched everywhere on the internet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a Positive integer or -1 to quit.");

        while (!s.nextLine().equals("-1")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a Positive integer or -1 to quit.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is not a 'Do my homework' kind of place. But think about actually STORING the strings input from the user (ArrayList?).

Comment: use s.nextInt() and keep track of each number entered[largest,smallest and mean].

Answer (score 0):

`s.nextLine()` reads your input

You should save it to a variable.

Also using a do-while to prevent the copied print statement

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String in;  // where to save next input value 

do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a Positive integer or -1 to quit.");
    in = s.nextLine();
    // TODO: parseInt, check for positive number 
}  while (!in.equals("-1"));
```

If you want to track mins and maxes, you need two additional integer values.

If you want to track averages, you need a list.

Best of luck

Comment: if I recall correct there's al.so a `.nextInt()` and `.nextDouble()` and so on for all primitive datatypes which neatly parse your data into such formats or just wait untill you use the proper format for that datatype.

Comment: There is, but for beginners, they don't realize that the newline character is not consumed when using said methods

Answer (score 0):

You first need to read integer from command line. For that you have to use

```
s.nextInt();
```

Once you get this you have to get largest and smallest number, you can get these using 2 variables.

For average you can store sum and number of times user asked for input, 2 more variable. No need to store elements in list or some other storage.

If you want to see numbers entered than you have to store else you don't have to.

For storing use :

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

For adding number you can use add method of List.

```
public static void main2() {
        Integer laregst = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Integer smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Integer sum = 0;
        Integer count =0 ;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int temp = s.nextInt();
        while (temp != -1) {
            if(temp > laregst){
                laregst = temp;
            }

            if(temp < smallest){
                smallest = temp;
            }

            sum += temp;
            count += 1;

            System.out.println("Please enter a Positive integer or -1 to quit.");
            temp = s.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Largest : "+(count == 0?"NA":laregst)+" Smallest : "+(count == 0?"NA":smallest)+" Mean : "+(count == 0 ? "NA" : ((sum *1.0/count))));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

if you wont to read Multible Integers Value in Same Line you Can use s.nextInt() to read one Integer Value in each time